# @JsonUnwrapped setting null as value for child pojo class

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

Request:

```
{
    "name":"iswarya",
    "dept":{
        "deptName":"eee",
        "location":"firstfloor"
    },
    "additionalDetails":{
        "projectName":"finalyearproject"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "name": "iswarya",
  "deptName": null,
  "location": null,
  "projectName": null
}
```

Controller class:

```
@PostMapping(value="/objectMApper")
public String createEmployee(@RequestBody AnnotationTestBean demoEntity) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper obj=new ObjectMapper();
    return obj.writeValueAsString(demoEntity);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `AnnotationTestBean `?

Comment: Please provide `AnnotationTestBean` class structure

Answer (score 0):

In the given example the request for JSON is not wrapped, so its `dept` and `additionalDetails` should not be annotated with `@JsonUnwrapped`.

Instead, a response should be created extending the request class, having a copy constructor, and overriding appropriate getters annotated as `@JsonUnwrapped`.

The example below uses Lombok annotations to generate getters/setters/constructors.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
static class Request {
    private String name;
    
    private Department dept;
    private Details additionalDetails;
}

@Data
static class Department {
    private String deptName;
    private String location;
}

@Data
static class Details {
    private String projectName;
}

static class Response extends Request { 

    public Response(Request request) {
        super(request.name, request.dept, request.additionalDetails);
    }

    @Override @JsonUnwrapped
    public Department getDept() { return super.getDept(); }

    @Override @JsonUnwrapped
    public Details getAdditionalDetails() { return super.getAdditionalDetails(); }
}
```

Test

```java
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

String json = "{\r\n" + 
        "    \"name\":\"iswarya\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"dept\":{\r\n" + 
        "        \"deptName\":\"eee\",\r\n" + 
        "        \"location\":\"firstfloor\"\r\n" + 
        "    },\r\n" + 
        "    \"additionalDetails\":{\r\n" + 
        "        \"projectName\":\"finalyearproject\"\r\n" + 
        "    }\r\n" + 
        "}";

Request request = om.readValue(json, Request.class);

Response response = new Response(request);
String str = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response);

System.out.println(str);
```

Output

```
{
  "name" : "iswarya",
  "deptName" : "eee",
  "location" : "firstfloor",
  "projectName" : "finalyearproject"
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. One more doubt -->Can't we use any JSON annotation in request bean class. Because i tried with many JSON annotation but it's setting null only. If not can u explain me why?

Comment: In company's project entity class exist with @JsonProperty annotation and using controller similar to above one which i mentioned but there its setting value